# Flutter display DropDown Widget multiple times in different classes

Tags: flutter, dropdown

I want to display the same dropdown on a different page.
Now I get the error:
There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: blue.
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value

This is my Dropdown class:

```
class DropDown extends StatelessWidget {
  late final String dropdownValue;
  final String itemsList;
  final TextEditingController textController;
  final List<String> categoryList = [
    "Hoodie",
    "Shoes",
    "Jeans",
    "Shirts",
  ];
  final List<String> colorList = [
    "pink",
    "red",
    "orange",
    "yellow",
    "lightgreen",
    "green",
    "turquise",
    "blue",
    "darkblue",
    "purple",
    "grey",
    "brown",
    "black",
    "white"
  ];

  DropDown(
      {required this.dropdownValue,
      required this.itemsList,
      required this.textController,
      Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<String> items;
    if (itemsList == "category") {
      items = categoryList;
    } else {
      items = colorList;
    }
    return DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
      value: dropdownValue,
      isExpanded: true,
      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
      elevation: 8,
      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 16),
      onChanged: (String? newValue) {
        dropdownValue = newValue!;
        textController.text = dropdownValue;
      },
      items: items.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: dropdownValue,
          child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0), child: Text(value)),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

I call it in my other classes like this:

```
 DropDown(
              dropdownValue: dropdownValueCategory,
              itemsList: "category",
              textController: categoryController
),
```

How can I display this Widget on different pages without this error?
Thank you very much!

Comment: var dropdownValue=null;Try  Initializing your dropdown value as null

Comment: This works for initialisation. But when I select a value, I have the same error again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the stateful widget for dropdown. You need to pass the data to the dropdown class from the first class. I have created the demo, manage the className as your desire.

Try as follows:

```
    class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
   final List<String> categoryList = [
    "Hoodie",
    "Shoes",
    "Jeans",
    "Shirts",
  ];
  final List<String> colorList = [
    "pink",
    "red",
    "orange",
    "yellow",
    "lightgreen",
    "green",
    "turquise",
    "blue",
    "darkblue",
    "purple",
    "grey",
    "brown",
    "black",
    "white"
  ];
  String catlistValue="";
  String  colorListValue="";
 void getDropDownValue(int i,String value){
    if(i==0){
      setState((){
        catlistValue=value;
      });
    }else{
       setState((){
        colorListValue=value;
      });
    }
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body:Column(children:[
        MyStatefulWidget(
        data:categoryList,
            getValueFunc:getDropDownValue,
          identifier:0,
        ),
       Text(catlistValue),
         MyStatefulWidget(
        data:colorList,
           getValueFunc:getDropDownValue,
           identifier:1,
        ),
     Text(colorListValue)
      ])
      
      
  );
  }
}
```

MyStatefulWidget contains the the dropdown

```
    class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
   final data;
  final getValueFunc;
  final identifier;
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key,this.data,this.getValueFunc,this.identifier}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  var dropdownValue ;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<String>(
      value: dropdownValue,
      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
      elevation: 16,
      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
      underline: Container(
        height: 2,
        color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
      ),
      onChanged: (String? newValue) {
        setState(() {
          dropdownValue = newValue!;
        });
        widget.getValueFunc(widget.identifier,dropdownValue);
      },
      items:widget.data.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: Text(value),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct, I think you are using the `Dropdown` somewhere with `dropdownValue: "blue"`, while you probably also said `itemsList: "category"`. If you want the colors you need to say anything else than "category", so for example `itemsList: "color"`.

But I would say that the design of the `DropDown` class in general isn't the best choice. I wouldn't make it that it needs a `itemsList` that's a string, but pass the `items` directly that you need

Comment: To put the items List in my Class was an approach to encounter this problem. So I want to reuse the Dropdown list with the same values. Is that not possible?

Comment: @jansemrau I told you what you can do. just write `itemsList: "color"` for example. The error you had comes from having a `dropdownValue` being a value not in the list